# Stored procedure OUT returns null value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure always returns a null value when I try to select it. I did some research and I have to specify somewhere OUTPUT. Not sure where or how to do that.

```
delimiter $$

Create Procedure ClientPurchases (IN idClient INT, outClientAvgPurchases DECIMAL (4,2))
BEGIN 

DECLARE PurchasesAvg DECIMAL(4,2) ;

set PurchasesAvg=
(SELECT AVG(PurchaseAmount) 
FROM Purchase
inner join Client on idClient=Client_idClient);
SET outClientAvgPurchases= PurchasesAvg;

END$$


CALL ClientPurchase(3, @purchase );

SELECT  @purchase as 'Purchase Total';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OUT` is a keyword that should precede the parameter name:

```
Create Procedure ClientPurchases (IN idClient INT, OUT ClientAvgPurchases DECIMAL (4,2))
...
SET ClientAvgPurchases= PurchasesAvg;
```

Comment: And my fields aren't null

Comment: Maybe your `SELECT` is not working as expected. Btw, you can just end the stored proc with a select statement instead of selecting, copying and selecting again.

Comment: It does highlight my select statement and it's telling me  "not a valid "input at this position. I am not missing any parenthesis or semicolon.

Comment: OMG NEVER MIND! I was calling the wrong procedure!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a procedure argument as `IN`, `OUT`, or `INOUT`.

```
Create Procedure ClientPurchases (
    IN idClient INT, 
    OUT outClientAvgPurchases DECIMAL (4,2))
  . . .
```

Read more about this at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html